# how do i know that app finished in android?

Tags: android

I hope to control app destroy.

I know that apps are generated through zygote. So if I want to control when app generated, I can do it using custom zygote.

However how do I know app finish? There are many case like fore, normal, abnormal and shutdown.

Is there a process that runs when all apps are shut down, like all apps are created via zygote?

In some case, `finishAffinity()`, `finishAndRemoveTask()` and `finish()` functions are used to finish the app. At that time what is process to handle these functions?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to understand **Android Activity Lifecycle** for this, check this official [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()).

This method will be called after activity `finish()`, so you can override this method and do anything you want:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Do stuff you want here
}
```

Hope this helps!